# Built in function not modifying in place (address changing unexpectedly)

Tags: r

In Advanced r ([section 6.5.2 Replacement Functions](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FfsYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT146&lpg=PT146&dq=replacement%20function%20in%20r%20address%20advanced%20r&source=bl&ots=x6ELzowSVo&sig=KOiZCYbxsK7InoaM4vdTQ7YxdxY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid4bbx2_3YAhVCPBQKHcZ9BWAQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=replacement%20function%20in%20r%20address%20advanced%20r&f=false)) it's stated that as opposed to a replacement function, built in functions implemented using primitive will modify in place (the address should stay the same after modification).

I don't find that to be the case, has this changed?  or are my tired eyes doing something wrong?

```
library(pryr)
x <- 1:10
pryr::address(x)
x[3] <- 7L
pryr::address(x)
```

Comment: If you are not using Rstudio, let me know and I can re-open the question. Otherwise it's a duplicate.

Comment: @MrFlick That responds perfectly to my question- thanks